# Javascript - Cannot display image from Express.js dockerized app

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, vue.js, express

After a lot of tries I finally managed to publish app on clients computer. Everything is working except images. I have Vue.js container, Node.js container, Mysql and Traefik container.
In vue I want to display image, which was uploaded to server by User. Problem is that after I tried everything, I can't get this to work.

Here is Vue.js function, where I receive photos from API call and append them to images.

```
async loadAllImages(){
      const caseId = this.bozpCases.id;
      CaseImagesService.getAllImages(caseId)
      .then((response) => {
        if(!response.data){
          throw "Error";
        }
        const data = response.data;
        const images = [];
        for (const id in data) {
          images.push({
            id: data[id].id,
            fileName: data[id].fileName,
            mimeType: data[id].mimeType,
            caseId: data[id].caseId,
            path: data[id].path,
          });
        }
        this.images = images;
        console.log('file name ' + images[0].fileName);
        console.log('mime type ' + images[0].mimeType);
        console.log('path ' + images[0].path);
      })
    },
  }
```

Here I am showing that image:

```
<section v-for="image in images" :key="image.id">
   <v-col>
      <v-img :src="`${image.fileName}`" max-height="125" max-width="125" />
   </v-col>
</section>
```

Here you can see what is being logged to console:

```
file name 19.06.2022,15:11:23-API.png
mime type image/png
path /usr/src/app/uploads
```

Also, here is my server.js part where I set express to use uploads folder.

```
app.use(express.static('uploads'))
```

I really don't know what can I change to make this work, I am trying to play with it from yesterday but nothing works. On localhost on my pc it was working this way.

Thanks

Comment: What's the value of `${image.fileName}`? Are you able to retrieve the image just by putting that value in as a url?

Comment: value of `${image.fileName}?` is name of picture. It was working for me like this when I was on localhost. But here on new server I am experiencing this error.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the full url instead of just the filename ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried to pass full url, path to container everything. When I send my request like this, requested url looks like this: 
`https://something.something.sk/19.06.2022,15:11:23-API.png`

I also tried this:
`https://something.something.sk/api/v1/19.06.2022,15:11:23-API.png`,
`https://something.something.sk/api/v1/uploads/19.06.2022,15:11:23-API.png`

but nothing works for me.